# GWT. Remove anchor part url

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, gwt-history

Hi I am using GWT and its standart way to support history via "History" class. It is very convenient but how can I remove anchor part from an url? For example:

My base url:

```
http://www.mysuperwebsite.com/myapp
```

While using application I move to a place that adds new history item.

In code:

```
History.newItem("funnygame");
```

As result:

```
http://www.mysuperwebsite.com/myapp#funnygame
```

I change place one more time:

In code:

```
History.newItem("notsofunnygames");
```

As result:

```
http://www.mysuperwebsite.com/myapp#notsofunnygames
```

Then I want to go back to my home page (http://www.mysuperwebsite.com/myapp).

What should be placed in code?:

```
????
```

to get back to:

```
http://www.mysuperwebsite.com/myapp
```

Is there any standart way I can achieve my goal?

---

If I add something like this:

```
History.newItem("");
```

or

```
History.newItem(null);
```

the url will become

```
http://www.mysuperwebsite.com/myapp#
```

And this is not what I am lloking for, I need it without sharp character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `History.newItem(null);` a new event will be fired.
As a result, you will toggle your home page :
`http://www.mysuperwebsite.com/myapp#`

Having or not a # at the end is the same thing, am I wrong ?

**EDIT:**

```
  ...
  // Get the last part of the url and remove #token
  String s = Location.getHref().substring(Location.getHref().lastIndexOf("/"));
  s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("#")-1);
  setToken(s);
  ...

  protected native void setToken(String token) /*-{
    $wnd.history.pushState({},'', token);
}-*/;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the first solution one will think about. I need it without "#". I will update my question.

Comment: The empty /myapp# fragment will have no effect, it's the same as /myapp in all ways.

Comment: It is the same while we are trying to retrieve place names from it, but it looks different in the location bar.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to remove the # is to replace the url or loop back until you reach your home (without #). I guess you don't want the page to be reloaded, neither looping back (that would be stupid). I've no idea right now...

Comment: You could try to use history.pushState which is introduced in HTML5 ? See my answer edited...

Comment: Although it looks like a workaround a bit, it is certainly the thing I was looking for! Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

The anchor is identified by a `#`, so you can use the following to remove it:

```
int index = link.indexOf('#');
if (index != -1) {
    link = link.substring(0, index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But you haven't understood me. I have updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: It is not suitable, cos I provided a very simple example, while it is far more complex in reality. A lot of places can be viewed before I need to go back to home view.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want a historytoken you are probably using history wrong. If you're not intending to fiddle with navigation i would recommend using GwtEvent / EventHandler. Which is essentially what gwt's History class does, in addition to linking those events to the navigation history.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tool class, and you call it when [History](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html) changes.

```
public class UrlUpdater {

    public static void removeHashIfEmpty() {
        if(isHashEmpty())
            removeHash();
    }

    private static boolean isHashEmpty() {
        return "#".equals(Window.Location.getHash());
    }

    private static void removeHash() {
        updateURLWithoutReloading(Window.Location.createUrlBuilder().setHash(null).buildString());
    }

    private static native void updateURLWithoutReloading(String newUrl) /*-{
        $wnd.history.replaceState({}, null, newUrl);
    }-*/;

}
```

Comment: It works in firefox, but not in chrome, I am checking for solution and get back